# Rickshaw tooltip control with R

Tags: r, tooltip, time-series, mousehover, rickshaw

I'm trying to make something similar to http://www.r-bloggers.com/rickshaw-d3-js-from-r-with-rcharts/ (manipulate rickshaw with R).
Is it possible to manage tooltip/hoverDetail? 
Like for example I'd like to get the difference of the values of two series at the point of mouse over?

Comment: It is possible using the `hoverDetail` method. I would suggest you provide a reproducible example that includes data and some code that you tried, and the effect that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Example 2
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_TEMPLATE = 'Rickshaw.html')
require(RColorBrewer)
data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
datm = reshape2::melt(
  economics[,c('date', 'psavert', 'uempmed')],
  id = 'date'
)
datm <- transform(datm, date = to_jsdate(date))
p2 <- Rickshaw$new()
p2$layer(value ~ date, group = 'variable', data = datm, type = 'line', 
  colors = c("darkred", "darkslategrey"))
```

That's one of the provided examples, and lets say I want my tooltip to show the difference between those two series.